# Thread Updates in discord.js - Type of update and editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a listener to the `threadUpdate` event, and is in the need of knowing what occurred.

The two things I need to know are:

- Who did this? (Was it manual or due to the autoArchive ?)
- What happened? (I only need to catch the thread lock and archiving events, nothing like renaming them.)

As tested, there are the `locked` and `archived` properties, however, they seem to be before the update, which makes it even harder to detect what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`threadUpdate` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-threadUpdate) takes two parameters, `oldThread` and `newThread`. You can compare these two to see what changed. If `oldThread` is not locked and `newThread` is locked then the `threadUpdate` event is fired because someone locked the thread. You can check the same with the `archived` property.

To find out who updated the thread, you will need to check the audit logs. Unfortunately, they are not guaranteed to arrive when you expect them (if at all) and there is no event which triggers when an audit log is created. However, I think this is the only way to see who updated your thread.

You can use the [`guild.fetchAuditLogs()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs) method to fetch the logs. It accepts an options object, which helps to limit it to a single entry and type. You can use the `AuditLogEvent.ThreadUpdate` enum for the type. It returns a collection of entries and you'll need to check the first one. You should also check if the entry `target` is the same thread as the one triggered the `threadUpdate` event.

```js
import { AuditLogEvent } from 'discord.js';

// no idea how your function looks like, so let's name it execute
async execute(oldThread, newThread) {
  if (
    oldThread.locked === newThread.locked &&
    oldThread.archived === newThread.archived
  ) {
    // there is no interesting change so it's time to exit
    return;
  }

  if (!oldThread.locked && newThread.locked) {
    console.log(`${newThread} is locked`);
  }
  if (oldThread.locked && !newThread.locked) {
    console.log(`${newThread} is unlocked`);
  }
  if (!oldThread.archived && newThread.archived) {
    console.log(`${newThread} is archived`);
  }
  if (oldThread.archived && !newThread.archived) {
    console.log(`${newThread} is unarchived`);
  }

  const fetchedLogs = await newThread.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
    limit: 1,
    type: AuditLogEvent.ThreadUpdate,
  });

  const log = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

  if (!log) {
    return console.log(
      'A thread was updated, but no relevant audit logs were found.',
    );
  }
  if (log.target.id === newThread.id) {
    console.log(`A thread was updated by ${log.executor?.tag}.`);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what `log.executor` is if the thread is archived automatically. It's probably best to `console.log` the value of `log` to see if you can find some relevant info. (Check `log.executor` and `log.changes`)